# How to remove white space around header image?

Tags: css

I am experimenting with my header but I can't remove the white space around it, this is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.header{background:url(http://likenation.com/theme/pes/images/header_bar.png) repeat-x;border-bottom:1px solid #131619;height:56px}
.header-content{width:1000px;margin:auto}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-content">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what the header looks like: http://gyazo.com/b71ad68c24c2bdb49619a44c551918c5.png

I would really appreciate if someone could help me fix this.

**EDIT:**

Since I can't answer my own question, I will post it here:

I added this:

```
html,body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

and it worked, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: have you tried specifying: body {width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; }

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if you've got a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to zero out the paddings/margins on your html/body:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I would probably use a [proper reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) the default CSS that is set by the browser; An easy way to do this is:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And if you want to reset more/all elements, you can check out severeal CSS reset files at http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: @Legionar So? That's the `Universal Selector "*"` reset, as found on http://www.cssreset.com/ - I don't know why the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit margin and padding for `body` that depends from browser to browser. As a good practice you can add `margin:0` and `padding:0` to body element